# Не могу запустить ТГ-бота

Tags: python, telebot, бот

Пытаюсь запустить своего телеграм-бота на собственном компьютере, но вылетает огромное количество ошибок. Раньше такого не было. Ошибок в коде точно нет, т.к. через VPN запускаю - работает всё нормально. Подскажите, это у меня на компьютере какие-то проблемы или это проблемы серверов телеграм? (пишу на фрейворке telebot без webhook) [image: куча ошибок при запуске]

Answer (score 0):

while True:

```
try:


    bot.polling(none_stop=True)





except Exception as e:


    print(e)


    time.sleep(2)
```

Попробуй это в самый конец поставить, должно помочь[image: фото]

Comment: Извините, но это не решило проблему. Бот теперь просто не падает и выводит огромное количество сообщений об ошибках. С VPN вообще никаких ошибок не выдаёт.